# Why do I get 'positional index out of bound' error only for a few inputs?

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a project where I return the search results for a particular topic from the dataset of scraped news articles. However, for few of the inputs, I get 'IndexError: positional index out of bounds' while for others, the code works just fine. I even tried to limit the number of outputs and printed the indexes of the rows which are to be printed just to be sure that '.iloc' does not return that error but it still is happening.

Data:

[image]

Code:

'''

```
def search_index(c):

    global input_str

    c = c.lower()
    c = re.sub("((\S+)?(http(S)?)(\S+))|((\S+)?(www)(\S+))|((\S+)?(\@)(\S+)?)", " ", c)
    c = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9\n]',' ',c)

    d = list(c.split())
    input_str = [word for word in d if word not in stop_words]
    print(input_str)
    e = OrderedDict()
    f = []
    temp=[]

    for index,content in data.iterrows():
        count = 0
        points = 0
        for i in input_str:
            if i in (content['word_count']).keys():
                #pdb.set_trace()
                count += 1                           # considering how many words from the input match with the content
                points += content['word_count'][i]   # considering the number of times those words occur in the content corpus

        if len(input_str)<=3:
            if count>=1:
                e[index] = {'count':count,'points':points}
                
        elif 3 < len(input_str) <=5:
            if count>=2:
                e[index] = {'count':count,'points':points}
            
        elif len(input_str) > 5:
            if count>=3:
                e[index] = {'count':count,'points':points}
                #print('\nIndex:',index,'\nContent:\n',content['Content'])


# the lambda function first sorts the dictionary based on the 'count' and then on the basis of 'points'
    for key,val in sorted(e.items(), key=lambda kv: (kv[1]['count'],kv[1]['points']),reverse=True):
        f.append(key)
        #print(key,val)

    #print(f)
    #data.iloc[f,:]
    print('Total number of results: ',len(f))    

    if len(f)>50 :
        temp=f[:20]
        print(temp)
        print('Top 20 results:\n')
        a = data.iloc[temp,[0,1,2,3]].copy()
    else:
        a = data.iloc[f,[0,1,2,3]].copy()
    
    print(a)
```

'''

'''

```
def user_ask():
        b = input('Enter the topic you''re interested in:')
        articles = search_index(b)
        print(articles)
```

'''

'''

```
user_ask()
```

'''

> Output: For this input I  am getting the required output

'''

```
Enter the topic youre interested in:Joe Biden
['joe', 'biden']
Total number of results:  2342
[2337, 3314, 4164, 3736, 3750, 3763, 4246, 3386, 3392, 13369, 3006, 4401, 
4089, 3787, 4198, 3236, 4432, 4097, 4179, 4413]
Top 20 results:

                                                Link  \
2467   https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/rep-max-rose-c...   
3471   https://abcnews.go.com/International/dalai-lam...   
4343   https://abcnews.go.com/US/georgia-legislation-...   
3910   https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/temperatures-c...   
3924   https://abcnews.go.com/Business/cheap-fuel-pul...   
3937   https://abcnews.go.com/US/puerto-ricans-demand...   
4425   https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/trump-biden-is...   
3543   https://abcnews.go.com/Business/record-number-...   
3549   https://abcnews.go.com/US/michigan-state-stude...   
17774  https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/bernie-sanders...   
3152   https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/note-gop-aids-...   
4583   https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/polls-show-tig...   
4268   https://abcnews.go.com/International/students-...   
3962   https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/heels-arizona-...   
4377   https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/north-carolina...   
3388   https://abcnews.go.com/Lifestyle/guy-fieri-lau...   
4614   https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/persistence-he...   
4276   https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/congressional-...   
4358   https://abcnews.go.com/US/nursing-home-connect...   
4595   https://abcnews.go.com/US/hurricane-sally-upda...   

                                               Title  \
2467   Rep. Max Rose calls on Trump to up COVID-19 ai...   
3471   The Dalai Lama's simple advice to navigating C...   
4343   Georgia lawmakers pass bill that gives court t...   
3910   Temperatures and carbon dioxide are up, regula...   
3924   Has cheap fuel pulled the plug on electric veh...   
3937   Puerto Ricans demand state of emergency amid r...   
4425       Trump vs. Biden on the issues: Foreign policy   
3543   Record number of women CEOs on this year's For...   
3549   All Michigan State students asked to quarantin...   
17774  Bernie Sanders, Danny Glover Attend Game 7 of ...   
3152   The Note: GOP aids Trump in programming around...   
4583   Trump adviser predicts Sunbelt sweep, misleads...   
4268   2 students allegedly caught up in Belarus crac...   
3962   On heels of Arizona Senate primary, Republican...   
4377   North Carolina to be a crucial battleground st...   
3388   Guy Fieri has helped raise over $22M for resta...   
4614   Little girls will have to wait 4 more years, W...   
4276   Congressional Black Caucus to propose policing...   
4358   Nursing home in Connecticut transferring all r...   
4595   Sally slams Gulf Coast with life-threatening f...   

                                             Content       Category  
2467   New York Rep. Max Rose joined “The View” Monda...       Politics  
3471   As millions of people around the world continu...  International  
4343   They've done their time behind bars and been o...             US  
3910   Every week we'll bring you some of the climate...       Politics  
3924   Electric vehicles have always been a tough sel...       Business  
3937   As Puerto Rico struggles to recover from multi...             US  
4425   American foreign policy for over half a centur...       Politics  
3543   A record high number of female CEOs are at the...       Business  
3549   All local Michigan State University students h...             US  
17774  — -- Bernie Sanders capped Memorial Day off by...       Politics  
3152   The TAKE with Rick Klein\nPresident Donald Tru...       Politics   
4583   Facing polls showing a competitive race in as ...       Politics  
4268   A U.S. student studying at New York’s Columbia...  International  
3962   What's sure to be one of the most expensive an...       Politics  
4377   North Carolina, home of the upcoming business ...       Politics  
3388   Guy Fieri should add donations to his triple d...      Lifestyle  
4614   Four years ago, a major political party nomina...       Politics  
4276   The Congressional Black Caucus is at work on a...       Politics  
4358   All residents at a Connecticut nursing home ar...             US  
4595   Sally made landfall near Gulf Shores, Alabama,...             US   
None
```

​

'''

> For this input it is  returning an error.

'''

```
Enter the topic youre interested in:Joe
['joe']
Total number of results:  2246
[4246, 4594, 3763, 3736, 4448, 2337, 3431, 3610, 3636, 4089, 13369, 15363, 
7269, 21077, 3299, 4372, 4413, 7053, 15256, 1305]
Top 20 results:

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-ff543d46b951> in <module>
----> 1 user_ask()

<ipython-input-27-31af284a01b4> in user_ask()
      4     if int(a) == 0:
      5         b = input('Enter the topic you''re interested in:')
----> 6         articles = search_index(b)
      7         print(articles)
      8 

<ipython-input-25-4a5261a1e717> in search_index(c)
     50         print(temp)
     51         print('Top 20 results:\n')
---> 52         a = data.iloc[temp,[0,1,2,3]].copy()
     53     else:
     54         a = data.iloc[f,[0,1,2,3]].copy()

c:\users\henis\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1759                 except (KeyError, IndexError, AttributeError):
   1760                     pass
-> 1761             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1762         else:
   1763             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

c:\users\henis\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
   2064     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup: Tuple):
   2065 
-> 2066         self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
   2067         try:
   2068             return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)

c:\users\henis\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _has_valid_tuple(self, key)
    700                 raise IndexingError("Too many indexers")
    701             try:
--> 702                 self._validate_key(k, i)
    703             except ValueError:
    704                 raise ValueError(

c:\users\henis\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _validate_key(self, key, axis)
   2006             # check that the key does not exceed the maximum size of the index
   2007             if len(arr) and (arr.max() >= len_axis or arr.min() < -len_axis):
-> 2008                 raise IndexError("positional indexers are out-of-bounds")
   2009         else:
   2010             raise ValueError(f"Can only index by location with a 
[{self._valid_types}]")

IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds
```

'''

Comment: Please post the actual text of the error, [formatted as code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), not a screenshot of it. It makes it harder for us to follow / debug if we do not have the actual text on our side as well.

Comment: Also, please make a [mre], so that we can copy and paste your code into our interpreter and encounter the same error.

Comment: I have done the suggested edits. However I would not be able to share the dataset as it is a really big file. Having said that, I suspect that the reason for the error that I am getting, is due to some minute detail I am missing in the code as it is returning an error only for some of the inputs. @HampusLarsson